# ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref' in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.5, importerror

I get the following error in Ubuntu 16.04 when I try to use commands like `pip`, `pip3`, `pipenv`, `virtualenv`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref
```

I have both Python 2.7, Python 3.5, and Python 3.7 installed. When I type `python` in the command prompt I get this:

```
root@genopathngs-Precision-Tower-3620:/usr/local/bin# python   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/issues/1739) is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].